3D printer not printing after damaging bed
I'm still very new to 3D printing. My first few prints turned out great, but I've unfortunately damaged my print bed.
Do I need to replace both the bed and the nozzle? I can’t seem to get the filament to extrude, even after heating and cleaning.

Bed

Walked away and left it silly me the bed was way off.
The filament doesn't even seem to be coming out. But the beds knackered which doesn't help. Is there a way of testing the filament is working and releasing properly without having to actually print something?
Nozzle


Could you please add some photos showing what the damaged heat bed and nozzle look like?

How damaged is the bed that you aren't able to print? Damaging the bed usually indicates that the bed needs re-tramming because of the nozzle touching the bed surface or damaging with print removal. A photo would speak a thousand words!

Your printer appears to be a Creality Ender v1. I ended up replacing my bed topper with a PEI sheet from Aliexpress. That will replace the scratching.
To confirm filament coming out of the nozzle, do a Preheat-PLA in the printer menu. Wait for it to heat fully, then do an Extrude either through the menu or by simply cranking the wheel on top of the extruder motor. You should see a thin stream of molten filament drop out of the nozzle and hang there.
If no soft filament comes out, you might have a lack of "push" in the extruder gears, or a blockage in the nozzle. This means pulling the Bowden tube, retracting the unused filament, etc. There should be a fine wire in the printer toolkit, which can be used to poke up the nozzle to dislodge blockages.
Note: the nozzle has to be hot to unscrew with a ring spanner. Also, hot nozzles at 200 °C will burn you incredibly fast, so don't touch it with bare hands.
Ender 3s are quite old now, so there's a good chance your Bowden tube is a little crispy at the nozzle end. The advantage of an older printer is there are lots of helpful posts on fixing things like this.

Thanks I'll give these a ho in the next day or so and see how I get on
